# Crontab Won't Save Images From PHP Script

Tags: php, save, cron, image-resizing

I have a PHP script that scrapes images from an RSS feed, resizes them and then saves them. I made a cron job via crontab that will do this once per hour but the images are not saved.

I thought it was a permissions error and the owner of the folder is www-data and the crontab user I set it up in is also www-data so I'm not quite sure what's going on.

The script runs fine from the browser.

The crontab code I am using is:

```
56 * * * * /usr/bin/php5 /home/user/public/site.com/public/script.php
```

I also tried curl with no success but I'm not 100% sure I made it correctly.

Everything else works, it stores the text for example just fine. It also names the images correctly it just doesn't save them

Comment: do you actually gen an error somewhere in your script? have you added debugging messages (or a log file) that records the return values of functions such as `fopen()`?

Comment: hit the script from the command line as root, still fail?

Comment: When I try to add a log the cron job doesn't run at all. I also tried to look in /var/log/cron and that file doesn't exist. I tried running as root as well.

Comment: What happens if you run it manually from the cli, i.e. >php /home/user/public/site.com/public/script.php

Comment: Okay I ran from CLI and had issues, spent some time fixing them (path issues) and got it working correctly via CLI. But I still can't get it to work in crontab.

Comment: I made a test script that will simply delete an image. I add cron jobs in my user, as sudo and as www-data - and can not get them to work. When I run the script in CLI it works just fine. I think it's a permissions error because of this - I went so far as to 777 an image (and the folder as well) and still can't get it to delete from crontab.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to run the crontab job as a specific user. The cronjob probably isn't running as you.

```
56 * * * *  <USER_NAME_HERE> /usr/bin/php5 /home/user/public/site.com/public/script.php
```

Comment: Crontab doesn't allow that as far as I know, I see this:

    m h dom mon dow command

so to run as a user I use: 

    sudo crontab -u www-data -e

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

This time it turned out to be user error (shocking right) - I did not include the correct full path. Thank you all for replying.

I guess the lesson here is to include more information next time when I ask a question I should have posted more code.